# Building list of dicts from csv using Python

Tags: python, list, csv, dictionary

I have a CSV file containing three columns and many rows.  All the data is Strings.  I am trying to read the CSV one line at a time and convert each row to a Dict which I then want to append to a list so I have a List of Dicts.  The environment is AWS Lambda and the CSV comes from an S3 bucket.

My code:

```
csv_object = s3.Object('MyBucket', 'My.csv')
csv_file = csv_object.get()['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')

f = StringIO(csv_file)
reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')

list_of_json = []
mydevice = {}

for row in reader:
    mydevice["device"] = row[0]
    mydevice["serial"] = row[1]
    mydevice["software"] = row[2]

    list_of_json.append(mydevice)
```

The software runs *(ie, doesn't error)*, but it doesn't produce the desired result.  If I `print(list_of_json)` after the for loop completes, I want it to produce this;

```
[{"device":"Dev1", "serial":"Ser1", "software":"software1"},{.....}]
```

But what is actually produces is just an empty list... as if the append statement doesn't even exist;

```
[]
```

The CSV reading and `for row in reader:` parts all seem to work fine.  If I do a print(mydevice) inside the for loop I can see it working its way through all the devices successfully, but for reasons I can't fathom, the append statement never seems to append anything to the `list_of_json` list.

Comment: Have you tried using the DictReader? it does what you appear to be trying to do. Also could you add a sample input CSV so we can try running your code?

Comment: Were you running this in the interpreter, looping over it once printing out `mydevice` and the next appending to the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a new dictionary inside the loop:

```
csv_object = s3.Object('MyBucket', 'My.csv')
csv_file = csv_object.get()['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')

f = StringIO(csv_file)
reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')

list_of_json = []

for row in reader:
    mydevice = {}
    mydevice["device"] = row[0]
    mydevice["serial"] = row[1]
    mydevice["software"] = row[2]
    list_of_json.append(mydevice)
```

Comment: This is true but wouldn't explain why nothing is appended to the list. As the code is in the question, I'd expect the same dictionary to be added multiple times.

Comment: Argh!  That did the trick  -  thank you.  Any idea why defining the Dict inside the for loop works, but defining it outside doesn't?

Comment: Defining it outside the loop means you're overwriting the existing keys/values each time. Inside the loop you are creating new objects each time so changes do not affect the data from previous rows.

Comment: Yes, you need to create a new dictionary object every time.

Comment: But, why did he get an empty list as opposed to a list of identical dictionaries (i.e. he claimed he was getting [])?

Comment: That does looks odd. I tried this with a Python 3.6.6 and you indeed get a list with multiple references to the same dictionary.

Comment: I'm on Python 2.7 (yes I know I need to upgrade!)

Answer (score 3):

Why not just use [`csv.DictReader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader)

```
csv_object = s3.Object('MyBucket', 'My.csv')
csv_file = csv_object.get()['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')

f = StringIO(csv_file)
reader = csv.DictReader(f, ('device', 'serial', 'software'))
list_of_json = [dict(device) for device in reader]
#also don't forget to
f.close() #or use contextlib.closing
```

Comment: Is closing as important if it's an in memory file object?

Comment: I'm unsure but it's good practice, as you don't need the reader anymore, to safely close it